# Laravel 4 - Model not being saved

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Having this code:

```
class SearchIndex extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'searchindex';

    //no timestamps
    public $timestamps = false;

    //mass-assignment
    public $fillable = array('url', 'content', 'version', 'digest');
    public $guarded = array();

    public static function updateIndex($url, $version, $content)
    {
        self::retrieveSearchEntry($url, $version)->updateContent($content)->save();
    }

    public static function retrieveSearchEntry($url, $version)
    {
        try
        {
            return self::withoutContent()->where('url', $url)->where('version', $version)->firstOrFail(array('url', 'version', 'digest'));
        }
        catch(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e)
        {
            return new SearchIndex(array('url' => $url, 'version' => $version));
        }
    }

    public function updateContent($content)
    {
        $hash = md5($content);
        if (!isset($this->digest) || ($this->digest != $hash))
        {
            $this->content = $content;
            $this->digest = $hash;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public static function search($content)
    {

    }
}
```

If I call `updateIndex` providing a new combination of url+version, an entry is created.
If I call `updateIndex` providing an existing pair of url+version, **the entry is not updated with the new content**. I'm seeing it has something to do with the fact that I'm omitting the 'content' field (reason: is huge, and I want to set it, not get it, in that function).

**question**: How can I not-get the content field, but be able to set it when saving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Reason: I was not selecting the "id" field when doing the custom selection in firstOrFail(). In that way, id was null and the generated SQL tried to update (since it was an existent object) "where id is NULL", which would affect 0 rows.